# How can I use conditional operators to get the highest and lowest value among the five variables?

Tags: java

So far, I've only figured out how to get the highest and lowest values from the three variables using the conditional operator. Basically, this is what it looks like on the three variables:

```
int highnum = n1>n2?n1:n2; highnum = n3>highnum?n3:highnum;
```

Same concept goes to finding the lowest which is just replacing **(>)** with **(<)**.
When it comes to five variables, I still can't quite know how to write them.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by putting the second condition in the `else` part (i.e. the part which after `:`).

**Demo**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 15, y = 5, z = 10;
        int max = x > y && x > z ? x : y > x && y > z ? y : z;
        int min = x < y && x < z ? x : y < x && y < z ? y : z;

        System.out.println("Max: " + max + ", Min: " + min);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Max: 15, Min: 5
```

If you are prohibited from using `&&`, you can do it as follows:

```
int max = x > y ? (x > z ? x : z) : y > z ? y : z;
int min = x < y ? (x < z ? x : z) : y < z ? y : z;
```

Comment: How about with a five variables, Sir?

Comment: @jojocan'tcode In that case, the method remains the same but it will be too complex to manage. I suggest you use an array or a collection if you have more than three values.

Comment: You do not need to use parenthesis. I've used it just for better readability. You will get the same result even without it.

Answer (score 3):

## Starting Point

Let's assume that the variables are

- `n1`
- `n2`
- `n3`
- `n4`
- `n5`

## Doing it with ternary operator:

```
max = (max = (max = (max = (n1 > n2 ? n1 : n2)) > n3 ? max : n3) > n4 ? max : n4) > n5 ? max : n5;
```

This is incredibly messy (there might be a typo in the untested code above).

## Doing it with conditionals

```
max = n1;
if (n2 > max) max = n2;
if (n3 > max) max = n3;
if (n4 > max) max = n4;
if (n5 > max) max = n5;
```

## Doing it with arrays

```
int myArray = new int[] {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5};
int max = n1;
for (index = 1; index < myArray.length; index++) {
    if (max < myArray[index]) max = myArray[index];
}
```

## Doing it with Math.max

```
int max = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(n1, n2), n3), n4), n5)
```

## IntStream

As @Edwin Dalorzo pointed out in the comment section, `IntStream` is also a possible approach. This is the first time I have heard of `IntStream`, so the following example may be incorrect. If so, I graciously thank any issue pointed out about it:

```
IntStream.of(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5).reduce(max,Math::max)
```

Explanation (as far as I understand):

- we instantiate a stream by passing the 5 variables we have (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of-int...-)
- we call `reduce`, so, under the hood all elements are considered and the operator is applied (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-)
- we pass `max`, a variable as first parameter to `reduce`, to specify that we compute the maximum
- we pass `Math::max` as the operator, so `reduce` will compute the maximum.

Comment: Great set of examples. Perhaps you could consider providing stream example as well, `IntStream.of(n1,n2,…).reduce(Math::max,n1)`

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo thanks for the suggestion, added an example. This was untested and my first attempt to implement an `IntStream` example, so, please let me know if it's incorrect.

Comment: `IntStream.of(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5).max().getAsInt()` would also work.

Answer (score 2):

The optimal way is to use a loop/ define you own `max` function with [Varargs¹](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html).

It's very nasty to do it using only conditional operators, if you need it for an exercise you can do this:

```
int highnum = ((n1>n2 ? n1 : n2) > (n3>n4 ? n3 : n4) ? (n1>n2 ? n1:n2) : (n3>n4?n3:n4)) > n5 ? ((n1>n2 ? n1 : n2) > (n3>n4 ? n3 : n4) ? (n1>n2 ? n1:n2) : (n3>n4?n3:n4)) : n5;
```

Or you can define a method as following:

```
public static int max(int a,int b){
    return a>b?a:b;
}
```

and then do something like this:

```
int highnum = max(max(max(n1,n2),max(n4,n3)),n5);
```

1: Varargs method:

```
public static int max(int... nums){
    int max = nums[0];
    for (int num : nums) if(num>max) max=num;
    return max;
}

int highnum = max(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5);
```

Comment: I also agree that it's very nasty to do it using only conditional operators, but I do have an exercise that has the same concept as these, and for the sake of doing the exercise, I am committed to writing it that way, though I still get confused along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, don't feel it makes sense to do it with ternary operator for 5 variables.(Unless you want to train your brain).

Below just supplement on how to do it using Stream.

### Stream approach

Make use of [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and corresponding [`summaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics()) method:

```java
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class IntStatistic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n1 = 9;
        int n2 = 7;
        int n3 = 5;
        int n4 = 3;
        int n5 = 1;
        IntSummaryStatistics statistic = IntStream.of(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5).summaryStatistics();
        System.out.println("min " + statistic.getMin());
        System.out.println("max " + statistic.getMax());
    }
}
```